# How can I update multiple field records within a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns

I am trying to update multiple records with a `foreach` loop, but it replaces with the previous record:

[image: Table structure]

```
TableID ----  ProductID --- Color ---- ImageSample
```

```
foreach($Extras['ColorText'] as $key=>$val)
{
    $query = "update productcolor set 
    Color = '".$Extras['ColorText'][$i]."' Where
    ProductID = '".$RecordID."' ";
    echo $query;
    $App1->query($query);

    $i++;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<td align="left" valign="top">Product <br />
    <input type='text' name='Color[]' class='auto TextField' value="<?php echo $App->f("Color"); ?>"></td>
</td>
```

Query shown:

```
update productcolor set Color = 'sdasdas', ImageSample = '' Where ProductID = '93' update productcolor set Color = 'sdasdas', ImageSample = '' Where ProductID = '93' update productcolor set Color = 'Yellow', ImageSample = 'listing.png' Where ProductID = '93'
```

Comment: It's because you are always using the same value for `$RecordID`.

Comment: How can i achieve this i have to update multiple records with the same product id

Comment: get all rows with same product id, loop through rows, update each row in loop using different color, for this you can use array_pop on your colors array to get and remove a color from that array

Comment: A better idea might be too look at INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY, with the VALUES option